# How to join a consecutive tuples by comma in nested list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, tuples

I have a four inputs values from user as follows:

```
numbers[1, 2]
numbersLetters={'E': 1,'K': 2}
RandomFrequency="0.5"
```

Here, My aim is to randomize the numbers list and get the random no which has > 0.5.

Then, get the letter of selected random no from numbersLetters dictionary.

Finally, append all the matched random no along with respective letter in single tuples inside the list of another list.

Expected OUPUT something like this:

```
[[('1', 'E'), ('2', 'K')]]
```

WHAT I get:

```
[[('1', 'E')], [('2', 'K')]]
```

My script

```
import random

def randomMutation(numbers,numbersLetters,MF):
    mut=[]
    for res,pos in numbersLetters.iteritems():
        r = random.choice([x for x in numbers if x > MF])
        if pos==r:
            fp=int(pos)-1
            mut.append([tuple(str(pos)+res)])
    print mut

if __name__ == '__main__':
    randomMutation([1, 2],{'E': 1,'K': 2},"0.5")
```

I got an answer:

```
import random

def randomMutation(numbers,numbersLetters,MF):
    mut=[]
    for res,pos in numbersLetters.iteritems():
        r = random.choice([x for x in numbers if x > MF])
        if pos==r:
            fp=int(pos)-1
            mut.append((tuple(str(pos)+res)))#changes
    if not mut:
        print "The possibility of random positions is not available for given thresold value ( > "+ str(MF)+")"
    else:
        mutation_combinations = chain.from_iterable([list(combinations([mut], 1))])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    randomMutation([1, 2],{'E': 1,'K': 2},"0.5")
```

Comment: Why the list inside a list with tuples? Why not `[('1', 'E'), ('2', 'K')]`?

Comment: Your `x > MF` test can never pass if `MF` is a string, because Python 2 always sorts numbers before other types (so `2 > "0.5"` is always *false*). Are you sure you didn't pass in `0.5` *without* the quotes?

Comment: Yes I didn't pass , here I just mentioned it for giving example. Thanks

Comment: I want to put it in nested list because later I want to extract  based on list of tubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending a tuple *inside a list*:

```
mut.append([tuple(str(pos)+res)])
```

Remove the `[...]` brackets; these create your nested list objects, you don't need it:

```
mut.append(tuple(str(pos)+res))
```

Rather than concatenate characters then convert the string back to a tuple, just create the tuple directly:

```
mut.append((str(pos), res))
```

Comment: As your suggestion I created list of tuples by this line: mut.append(tuple(str(pos)+res). Then I got list of tuples as follows  mut=[('G', '1', 'E'), ('G', '2', 'K')]. Finally , I put this list into another list by mutation_combinations = chain.from_iterable([list(combinations([mut], 1))])

Comment: Its working with adding another line -> mutation_combinations = chain.from_iterable([list(combinations([mut], 1))]. I updated my correct script